# How to set border color using MUI styled components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add a border color to a styled component using MUI:

```
const Style = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    borderColor: theme.palette.success.main,
    border: 10, 
    borderTop: 10,
    width: INFO_WIDTH
}));
```

However, I don't see any change in the effect:
[Screenshot of browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or3wI.png)

I'm trying to follow the [guidelines](https://mui.com/system/borders/#border) specified by MUI but it's not working. Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 4):

The guidelines you linked to are for the `sx` prop (or lower-level usage of `@mui/system`) -- not the `styled` API. One key difference between the two is that for the `sx` prop, a numeric border value is [treated as a shorthand](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.4.4/packages/mui-system/src/borders.js#L12) for `${value}px solid`. The `styled` API does not automatically add `solid`, so `border: 10` just becomes `border: 10px` which is not sufficient for causing a border to be displayed.

A separate issue with your example is that you specify `borderColor` before `border`. Since `border` is a [shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) for `border-width`, `border-style`, and `border-color`, even when you don't specify a color with the `border` value, a previously specified `border-color` will be overridden with the default.

Below is an example showing the correct syntax for specifying the border for both `sx` and `styled`:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const StyledDiv = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  border: "10px solid",
  borderColor: theme.palette.success.main,
  width: "5rem",
  height: "5rem",
  margin: theme.spacing(1)
}));
export default function BorderSubtractive() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Box
        sx={{
          border: 10,
          borderColor: "success.main",
          width: "5rem",
          height: "5rem",
          m: 1
        }}
      />
      <StyledDiv />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Border MUI Demo]